# A good reference for determinacy (set theory and game theory)

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, game-theory

Looking for a subject to develop an undergraduate search project, I found the concept of Determinacy, a subfield of set theory that examines the conditions under which one player of a game has a winning strategy, as *Wikipedia* states. I've read just a little bit about it, so I'd like to get an introductory book to learn the concept and explore suitable applications. I'm a beginner in set theory and game theory and I'd be grateful with some indications and suggestions.

As far, I got Thomas Jech's *Set Theory*. In it, *Determinacy* is the name of chapter $33$. Since it doesn't present a diagram of interdependence between the chapters, I don't know if it'd be a good idea (the chapter $33$ starts at page $627$). Hrbacek and Jech's *Introduction to set theory* discusses it too, but I'd like to appeal to your opinion and maybe to find some better.

In short, let's say I'm interesting in a book by which it I could learn about Determinacy and find a nice application, like the proof of the determinacy in some class of games... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) books are the way to go; either [Kechris](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387943749) or [Moschovakis](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/dst2009/dst2009.pdf) will serve you well.

Personally, for a first introduction I vastly prefer Kechris; specifically, I would read the beginning few chapters to get a good sense of the context (Polish spaces, Borel sets, some tree combinatorics) and then would read chapters 20-21, diving back to the earlier chapters when needed.

Chapter 6 ("The playful universe") of Moschovakis goes into more sophisticated material, but is also much heavier.

Comment: I think that Kechris's book is heavier, but I don't remember holding both of them for comparison.